# rails installation dosn't work - can't check version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi I have installed passenger modul for apache2 and then i tried to install rails, with the command:

```
gem install rails
```

It seemed to be done well. But when I check the verison now with

```
rails --version
```

i got an error during this:

```
command not found....
```

Comment: did you restart your shell/terminal?

Comment: restarted whole mashine.

do I need to start rails? oder to add it in path var?

Comment: Double check that you're installing Rails in the dir you're expecting it to be in. Depending on your system, you can try "which rails" to track it down. You might need to play with your path to tell your computer where to find Rails.  https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/196812

Comment: Ya, check your PATH var too, check which rails

Comment: which raills -> no result, 

in which folder should it be?, I've got debian 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the PATH variable to folder where you have installed Rails, so when the 'rails' command will be triggered your system will know which program to launch.

Example: PATH=$PATH:/your_rails_folder

Comment: but where is the default path?